# Localization text when using the gamekit bluetooth (iphone)

Tags: iphone, localization

Does anyone know why when changing the language on the iphone, the bluetooth message does not change? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is intentional but when I deploy to the device, it is translated but not when running on the simulator... Hope this helps